# How to iterate over elements of same class to find first visible

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

If I had multiple objects of a class present, but only some are visible, what would be the best way to find the first visible one.  I currently try:

```
browser.waitForElementVisible('.myClass', timeOut)
```

which sees all of the elements, but will only act on the first found. OR

```
browser.waitForElementVisible('(//div[@class="myClass"])[1]')
```

which specifies an index, but that may or may not be visible, since new data is loaded every time the page refreshes.

I need to loop through all present and just click on the first instance of one that is visible.  I know I can achieve this through custom commands, but I'm new to js and nightwatch, so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would probably use `.elementIdDisplayed()` to accomplish this.

The snippet below should help you

- get a list of the elements
- check if one is displayed
- If displayed, click on the element

---

Usually I would use a `forEach` loop but since you can't break out of that without doing some hacky stuff just use a regular old for loop like this:

```
browser.elements('css selector', '.myClass', function(elements) {
    for(let i = 0; i < elements.value.length; i++) {
        browser.elementIdDisplayed(elements.value[i].ELEMENT, function(isDisplayed) {
            if(isDisplayed.value) {
                browser.elementIdClick(element.value[i].ELEMENT);
                break; //this will break out of the loop when you find the first displayed element
            }
        });
    }
});
```